# this grandfather of mine

Tags: meaning-in-context

> My father, Harald Dahl, was a Norwegian who came from a small town near Oslo, called Sarpsborg. His own father, my grandfather, was a fairly prosperous merchant who owned a store in Sarpsborg and traded in just about everything from cheese to chicken-wire.
>
> I am writing these words in 1984, but **this grandfather of mine** was born, believe it or not, in 1820, shortly after Wellington had defeated Napoleon at Waterloo. If my grandfather had been alive today he would have been one hundred and sixty-four years old. My father would have been one hundred and twenty-one. Both my father and my grandfather were late starters so far as children were concerned.

Why is there a "this" before grandfather? Does it imply there are 2 and more grandfathers?

Comment: This sort of usage of this as a determiner is usual when story telling!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a colloquial way of returning attention to the subject in question.

The form would be:

"Let me tell you about (some interesting entity). (some introduction).

"Then (some minor short digression).

"Anyway, **this** (interesting entity) ..."

In the context, "this" is used to remind the reader that they were originally discussing the (interesting entity), and now we are going to talk about it some more.

Whether or not the writer does still have 2 grandfathers is irrelevant.